# How assign to a class attribute an instance from another class residing on the same module

Tags: python

I cannot figure out to solve this problem:

```
class Clazz:
    EMPTY=Clazz1(None,None)

    def __init__(self):
        self.item=Clazz1("a","b")

class Clazz1:
    def __init__(self,key,value):
        self.key=key
        self.value=value

if __name__=='__main__':
   h=Clazz()
```

When I try to run it returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
   class Clazz:
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in Clazz
    EMPTY=Clazz1(None,None)
NameError: name 'Clazz1' is not defined
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clazz1` has to be defined before `Clazz`:

```
class Clazz1:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value


class Clazz:
    EMPTY = Clazz1(None, None)

    def __init__(self):
        self.item = Clazz1("a", "b")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   h = Clazz()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the Clazz1 definition before the Clazz.
If You don't do this Clazz can't see the Clazz1

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order of the classes (and read about the order of execution in python). You may find this helpful http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

```
class Clazz1:
    def __init__(self,key,value):
        self.key=key
        self.value=value


class Clazz:
    EMPTY=Clazz1(None,None)

    def __init__(self):
        self.item=Clazz1("a","b")


if __name__=='__main__':
    h=Clazz()
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time where it is needed, `Clazz1` does not exist yet.

Class definitions are executed immediately, so `Clazz1` must be defined before `Clazz`.

Note the difference to a fuinction definition, where the referred names must exist at run time:

```
def func():
    test = func1()

def func1():
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
   func()
```

When `func()` is finally called at the end, `func1()` exists so that it can perfectly be called.